# C++11 support in Emscripten

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, emscripten

I would like to compile a C++ code using Emscripten, where I use some C++11 features. Unfortunately I get an error:

```
index.cpp:13:18: error: expected expression
    vv.push_back({1.5f, 2.f});
                 ^
index.cpp:14:18: error: expected expression
    vv.push_back({5.f, 0});
                 ^
index.cpp:15:18: error: expected expression
    vv.push_back({1, 1});
                 ^
index.cpp:17:9: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for(auto& item : vv) {
        ^
index.cpp:17:20: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for(auto& item : vv) {
```

I can't understand, why I get this errors. The newest Emscripten and Clang versions are activated using `emsdk`.

The code is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

struct AA {
    float a;
    float b;
};

int main() {

    std::vector<AA> vv;

    vv.push_back({1.5f, 2.f});
    vv.push_back({5.f, 0});
    vv.push_back({1, 1});

    for(auto& item : vv) {

        std::cout << item.a << ' ' << item.b << std::endl;

    }

}
```

I even get a message: `LLVM version appears incorrect (seeing "4.0", expected "3.7")`

If it is true, it should wotk, because "Clang 3.3 and later implement all of the ISO C++ 2011 standard."

Comment: are you using the `-std=c++11` compiler flag? no, if I understand correctly ("warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension")

Comment: I get these errors, even if I add `-Wc++11-extensions`

Comment: max66 told you about `-std=c++11`. Why did you respond about some other, unrelated switch? What thought process led to that decision?

Comment: Because it was in the compiler log. Thank you for the help. It was new for me, that I have to explicitly enable C++11 features even in the newest clang

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Suggestion: add `-std=c++11` to your compiler options.

`-Wc++11-extensions` is a flag to add warnings, not to add C++11 support.

Comment: In which Clang version are the C++11 features enabled by default? I thought it is enabled since 3.3

Comment: @IterAtor: Why do you think that? Please point us to documentation that states it. All I see in [the Clang 3.3 release notes](http://releases.llvm.org/3.3/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html) is: _"Clang now has a feature-complete implementation of C++11, which can be enabled with the -std=c++11 command-line flag"_ which directly contradicts your claim.

Comment: @IterAtor - clang support C++11 starting from 2.9 (if I'm not wrong) but not by default. By default compile C++98; if you want C++11, you have to add `-std=c++11` (or `-std=c++0x` on older versions)